# Powershell - xml removeall & looping

Tags: powershell, parent

I have a source XML file and I need to verify if the AddressType used matches against one of those used in an application. If the AddressType matches those defined in the app then everything is ok and do nothing else.
However, if the AddressType does not match then delete the whole provider from the XML file.
I am pulling type codes back from the app via rest method and putting them in an array.
The comparison is working fine - the trouble occurs when I remove the provider. The first provider is removed ok from the xml file but none of the remaining providers are removed.

These are the type codes from the app.

```
HQ
MAIN
NOT_STATED
OP
```

And this is a sample xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="1">
    <OrganisationId>ID1</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER_1</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressType>TYPE1A</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
        <AddressesRow num="2">
        <AddressType>TYPE1B</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>

  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="2">
    <OrganisationId>ID2</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER_2</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressType>TYPE2A</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
      <AddressesRow num="2">
        <AddressType>TYPE2B</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>

    <OrganisationUnitsRow num="3">
    <OrganisationId>ID3</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER_3</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="3">
        <AddressType>TYPE3A</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>

</OrganisationUnits>
```

So in the sample xml file I have 5 AddressType lines (spread across 3 different providers) which do not match the type from the app so all 3 providers should be deleted.

And this is my code snippet.

```
#Define the source XML file path
$XMLPath = "$Provider_Root\TEST\source5.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $XMLPath)

## username and password to be used for web application login
$acctname = 'user1'
$password = 'letmein'

$params = @{uri = 'http://localhost:8080/providers/settings/provider/providerAddressTypes';
                   Method = 'Get'; #(or POST, or whatever)
                   Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($acctname):$($password)"));
           } #end headers hash table
   } #end $params hash table

# This gets all the basic info ok
$var = invoke-restmethod @params

#show the values in the console
echo $var.code

#The app returns the following codes
#  HQ
#  MAIN
#  NOT_STATED
#  OP


#echo $var.Length
$total = $var.Length
write-host "AddressType records in application = $total"

#Count the number of AddressTypes that we are getting back from the app via the web call, if it is greater than zero, then we are getting data back ok.
if ($var.Length -gt 0)
{

    #Loop through the XML file looking for the AddressRow
    foreach($AddressRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.Addresses.AddressesRow)
    {

        #Get the organisation ID - used for reporting purposes
        $OrgID = $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.OrganisationId

        #Get the root provider path so that we can delete it later
        $unitrow = $xml.OrganisationUnits.item('OrganisationUnitsRow')

        #Get the AddressType from the XML file in text format
        $n = $AddressRow.Item('AddressType')."#text"

        #Get the AddressType from the XML file
        $p = $AddressRow.Item('AddressType')



        #if the source XML file AddressType (stored in $n) is found in the array of app results (stored in an array $var.code) then we have a match and the provider is OK.
        if ($var.code -contains $n)
        #if ($var.code -eq $n)
        {
            echo "MATCH. xml source value is $n which matches a value in the app. Provider ID $OrgID"
        }
        # The XML file AddressType (stored in $n) is NOT found in the array of the app results (web query stored in an array $var.code) then the entire provider must be DELETED from the XML file.
        else
        {
            echo "NO MATCH. Source XML File value is $n. Provider ID $OrgID"

            #This removes the entire provider (I think)
            $unitrow.RemoveAll()    

            $xml.Save($XMLPath)
            $xml.Save($xml)
        }

    }

}
else
{
# No AddressType records were pulled back from the app, this could be an error.
echo "No AddressType records found in the app, this could be an error"

}

}
```

The console output from my powershell script looks like this.

```
HQ
MAIN
NOT_STATED
OP
AddressType records in application = 4
NO MATCH. Source XML File value is TYPE1A. Provider ID ID1 ID2 ID3
NO MATCH. Source XML File value is TYPE1B. Provider ID ID2 ID3
NO MATCH. Source XML File value is TYPE2A. Provider ID ID2 ID3
NO MATCH. Source XML File value is TYPE2B. Provider ID ID2 ID3
NO MATCH. Source XML File value is TYPE3A. Provider ID ID2 ID3
```

So the issues are
1. Only the first provider ID1 has been removed. 
2. It has left the  in place. If those are manually deleted and the script run again it removes the next provider and then stops.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="2">
    <OrganisationId>ID2</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER_2</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressType>TYPE2A</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
      <AddressesRow num="2">
        <AddressType>TYPE2B</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="3">
    <OrganisationId>ID3</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER_3</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="3">
        <AddressType>TYPE3A</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

It might be that I'm not removing the OrganisationUnitsRow correctly in order to delete the whole provider using $unitrow.RemoveAll() , I just cant see it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you try to remove a parent node while checking the first child so the second one won't exist anymore. There were other issues as well, but it's better to look at a correct and simple example. In the outer loop we iterate the entities that might get removed, in the inner loop we check the children.

```
$IsModified = $false
foreach ($UnitRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow) {
    $OrgID = $UnitRow.OrganisationId
    foreach ($AddressRow in $UnitRow.Addresses.AddressesRow) {
        $n = $AddressRow.AddressType
        if ($var.code -contains $n) {
            echo "MATCH. blabla"
        } else {
            echo "NO MATCH. blabla"
            $UnitRow.parentNode.RemoveChild($UnitRow) >$null
            $IsModified = $true
            break
        }
    }
}

if ($IsModified) {
    $xml.Save($XMLPath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution:

```
if ($var.Count -gt 0) {
    [string]$xpath = '/OrganisationUnits/OrganisationUnitsRow[not(./Addresses/AddressesRow/AddressType/text()[{0}])]' -f (($var | %{". = '{0}'" -f ($_ -replace "'","''")}) -join ' or ')
    $xml.SelectNodes($xpath) | %{$_.RemoveAll()} 
}
#output result to console to show what's been done
$xml | Format-Xml
```

**Explanation**

- `$xml.SelectNodes($xpath)` - find all nodes which meet our criteria
- `%{$_.RemoveAll()}` - and remove them

The criteria mentioned above (i.e. the `$xpath` variable) is where we implement your requirement of finding any organisations/providers who have an address which is not of the desired address type (or have no address type given).

- `'/OrganisationUnits/OrganisationUnitsRow` - The element to be returned is the `OrganisationUnitsRow`
- `[` - we filter for those rows for which the following is true
- `not(` - return the rows where there is not
- `./Addresses/AddressesRow/AddressType` - an address row which has an address type
- `/text()` - with a text value
- `[{0}]` which matches the condition we pass in

The condition we put into the text path just says "where the value is in the $var list; and is created as such:
- `$var | %{` - for each value in `$var`
- `". = '{0}'"` - create a statement `". = 'singleValueFromVar'"`
- `($_ -replace "'","''")` - NB: any single quotes in a value in var would cause problems, so we escape them by replacing `'` with `''`. 
- -join ' or '`- join all the values together with`or` statements

i.e. `$xpath` is given the value:

`/OrganisationUnits/OrganisationUnitsRow[not(./Addresses/AddressesRow/AddressType/text()[. = 'HQ' or . = 'MAIN' or . = 'NOT_STATED' or . = 'OP'])]`

**Full Sample Code**

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="2">
    <OrganisationId>ID2</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER_2</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressType>TYPE2A</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
      <AddressesRow num="2">
        <AddressType>TYPE2B</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="3">
    <OrganisationId>ID3</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>PROVIDER_3</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="3">
        <AddressType>HQ</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
"@

clear-host
[string[]]$var = @('HQ','MAIN','NOT_STATED','OP')
if ($var.Count -gt 0) {
    [string]$xpath = '/OrganisationUnits/OrganisationUnitsRow[not(./Addresses/AddressesRow/AddressType/text()[{0}])]' -f (($var | %{". = '{0}'" -f ($_ -replace "'","''")}) -join ' or ')
    $xml.SelectNodes($xpath) | %{$_.RemoveAll()} 
}
#output result to console to show what's been done
$xml | Format-Xml
```